# How can I edit an unnecessary <style> tag on my wordpress website head

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes, code-snippets

My website frameless.ca has a random style tag code snippet added at the end of the head which makes the website loop once before fully loading, it is very annoying and increases bounce rate chance. how can I edit this code, so that i can cancel this loop. I cannot locate it in theme editor section, and the custom css code section of the theme is fully empty as well. Im out of ideas, please help!

```
<style type="text/css"title="dynamic-css"class="options-output">
```

Comment: I guess one of the plugins added that `style` tag into your website `head`. You can try to disable plugins one by one and find out which one did that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in your  tag, it should be accessible from Appearance > Editor, then look for "Theme Header" or header.php file. Generally, those stylesheet links are at the top or bottom of the  tag

[UPDATE]

I went to your site to look at the tag, and it appears to be a needed style section for header-image functionality. It may be a stylesheet from your header—image-slider you have installed, or that came pre-packaged with the theme. I would advise against deleting it or turning it off without installing a third-party header plugin such as RevSlider or LayerSlider.

Comment: Any ideas on how i can edit that code snippet, if i can turn off the transition stuff, it might fix the issue without having to remove it. I am not sure what you mean when you say header-image slider, is the header logo image or the image slider in the body? ( which i tried disabling, and still nothing)

Comment: @MohammadHendesi the image slider at the very top of the webpage is what I’m referring to. Regardless of if you turn it off of the homepage, that style sheet is still going to remain. You have to disable the plugin in order to get rid of it. To edit it, you might be able to get it from Plugins > Editor. It should be a style sheet (.css) file, or it’ll be in one of the PHP files. Are you 100% certain it’s that style sheet? Generally style sheets don’t cause a loop. Generally that’s a PHP or JS issue.